# Use variable in replace regex

Tags: regex, sed

I've already looked at the following:

[Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

[Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

They give absolutely no easy to understand answer.

```
version=1.2.3
sed -i -z -e 's/"version": "[A-Za-z0-9_.-]*"/"version": "$(version)"/' package.json
```

I'm trying to use a variable in a replace regular expression in a file. I don't have to use sed per say, as long as it works on macs and linux dists I'm ok with it.

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/"version": "[^"]*"/"version": "'"$version"'"/'  package.json` or `sed -i -e 's/\("version": "\)[^"]*/\1'"$version"'/' package.json`

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to use double quote for sed to recognise the 4version variable, then just escape the double quotes which are included otherwise.

```
sed -i -z -e "s/\"version\": \"[A-Za-z0-9_.-]*\"/\"version\": \"$version\"/" package.json
```